# Add multiple lines to many arrays with the same source

Tags: php, arrays

I want to add every blog post into an array but I don't want to have every new line to be in one line. Why I want it to an array is because I want to get a space between each blog post with `implode('the space element', $array);` but not under the last blog post on the page.

**What I don't want:**

```
$array[] = '<section id="title"><header><a href="...
```

**What I want:**

```
# TITLE
$array[] = '<section id="title">';

    # TEXT
    $array[] .= '<header>';
        $array[] .= '<a href="'.url('post/'.date('Y/m/d', strtotime($post['datetime_published'])).'/'.(int)$post['id']).'">';
            $array[] .= $post['data_title'];
        $array[] .= '</a>';
    $array[] .= '</header>';

    and so on...
```

As you can see, I have already tried once possible solution but the website doesn't look that good if I do so.

**With simple echo's:**
[image]

**With the array code I want to have:**
[image]

How can I accomplish what I am after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code is actually only adding another element to the array each time, not concating the string.

```
$array[] = 'start ';
$array[] .= 'some text';
```

will output

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "start "
  [1]=>
  string(9) "some text"
}
```

I think what you want to do is add the text to a variable, then add the variable to the array.

Doing it like this:

```
$text = 'start ';
$text .= 'some text';

$array[] = $text;
```

will output:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(15) "start some text"
}
```

I'll leave you to put it in the loop with the correct values.